# How to remove AND add to array in Mongoose? (NodeJS)

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update an array based on differences in it.

For example, I have this:

```
...
tags: ['foo', 'bar'],
...
```

and I'd like to update it with the following model array **['foo', 'baz']** so that it becomes:

```
...
tags: ['foo', 'baz'],
...
```

As you can see, it will leave 'foo' in the model array, but it will take out 'bar', and it will add 'baz' because it's in the model array.

Now, what I'm currently doing is this:

```
$addToSet: {
  tags: {
    $each: req.body.conversation.tags
  }
}
```

Which is great, only for **adding tags...** Not removing any tags that are provided in the request's body. How should I structure my query so that I'm able to add and remove any items from my array dynamically **without duplicates?**

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can then use the slice command to remove the `'bar'` using the same technique as this:

`{ $slice: [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], 2 ] }` will return `[1, 2]`

Save the sliced array as your new array and then simply push the new variable to the array.

Don't think there is a single function that can accomplish this.